# Pandas apply function with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like do a `.apply` to a pandas DataFrame with condition. Here's the sample Dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import NaN

df = pd.DataFrame({'Area': [1, 9, NaN],
                   'Val': [1, 3, 5],
                   'Val2': [7, 9, 10]}) 

def sample_func(v1, token):
    sq = v**2
    return int(sq)

# Apply function

df['Area'] = df.apply(lambda x: sample_func(x['Val'], x['Val2']), axis = 1)
```

I'd like to modify the above apply statement to only include rows where column `Area` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a series of true/false to mask the rows that should not be converted. Use that to filter the row labels and you'll have the subset of rows you want to calculate.

One oddity of numpy as that `NaN` doesn't equal `NaN`, but the `isnone()` method sorts that out for you. Since you have NaNs in the Area column, its not an int type, so instead of doing `int(sq)` only for the rows of interest, I convert the entire column when done. By selecting the "Val" column before the apply, you can skip the lambda.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import NaN

# note the strange area to make sure we aren't recalculating non-NaN areas
df = pd.DataFrame({'Area': [1, 999, NaN],
                   'Val': [1, 3, 5]})
mask = df['Area'].isnull()

def sample_func(v):
    sq = v**2
    return int(sq)

df.loc[mask, 'Area'] = df.loc[mask]['Val'].apply(sample_func)
df['Area'] = df['Area'].astype(int)

print(df)
```

`apply` is slow. Broadcast ufuns when possible. In this case, you can square the entire column without the apply.

```
df.loc[mask, 'Area'] = (df.loc[mask]['Val'] ** 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `combine_first`:

```
df['Area'] = df['Area'].combine_first(df['Val'].apply(sample_func))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Area  Val
0   1.0    1
1   9.0    3
2  25.0    5
```

Comment: how do I use `combine_first` and `.apply` and pass multiple arguments to the function? Instead of passing just `df['Val']`, I'd like to pass additional arguments too.

Comment: `.apply(sample_func, val1, arg2=val2)`. The first implicit argument when you use `Series.apply` is the values of the column (here 'Val')

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`pandas.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df["Area"] = df["Area"].where(~df["Area"].isnull(), df["Val"].apply(sample_func))
```

- Where `df["Area"]` is not (`~`) null, keep the original value
- Where the condition is False, i.e. df["Area"] *is* null, substitute with values from `sample_func` applied on `df["Val"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['area'].isna(), 'Area'] = df.loc[df['area'].isna()].apply(lambda x: sample_func(x['Val']), axis = 1)
```